# Getting specific values in hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am trying to pull some values from a hashtable as described below.  First the hashtable contains some dates (CD) and git branch names (PR).   I am wanting to pull the date (CD) where PR contains a certain value like 'DS-8069'.

`$hashtable.Value`

```
CD                               PR
--                               --
2023-07-19T20:19:13.962350+00:00 refs/heads/ORION-565
2023-07-19T19:08:12.724945+00:00 refs/heads/DS-8313
2023-07-18T15:09:56.078588+00:00 refs/heads/ORION-514
2023-07-12T15:36:10.402005+00:00 refs/heads/IncentivePlanChanges
2023-07-06T15:52:52.855262+00:00 refs/heads/ORION-620
2023-07-05T15:42:43.350051+00:00 refs/heads/ORION-620
2023-06-30T07:58:58.265465+00:00 refs/heads/master
2023-06-21T16:06:33.740746+00:00 refs/heads/callback-polling-poc
2023-06-20T18:26:51.985011+00:00 refs/heads/ORION-513
2023-06-15T00:52:35.098398+00:00 refs/heads/DS-8069
2023-06-13T20:22:54.930335+00:00 refs/heads/DS-8069
2023-06-01T13:35:00.489204+00:00 refs/heads/DS-8069
2023-05-25T19:04:19.365357+00:00 refs/heads/ORION-531_1
```

`$hashtable.Value.PR`

```
refs/heads/ORION-565
refs/heads/DS-8313
refs/heads/ORION-514
refs/heads/IncentivePlanChanges
refs/heads/ORION-620
refs/heads/ORION-620
refs/heads/master
refs/heads/callback-polling-poc
refs/heads/ORION-513
refs/heads/DS-8069
refs/heads/DS-8069
refs/heads/DS-8069
refs/heads/ORION-531_1
```

I have tried a number of things to return just the date (CD) where the PR value contains some value

```
  `$hashtable.Value.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_ -contains 'DS-8069'}`
```

I get nothing

```
  `$hashtable.Value.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.value -contains "DS-8069"}`
```

I get nothing.

I am hoping to get back

```
2023-06-15T00:52:35.098398+00:00
2023-06-13T20:22:54.930335+00:00
2023-06-01T13:35:00.489204+00:00
```

How can I pull the date CD where the PR value contains some text?

thanks in advance

```
$hashtable


Name                           Value
----                           -----
Count                          61
value                          {@{CD=2023-07-19T20:19:13.962350+00:00; PR=refs/heads/ORION-565}, @{CD=2023-07-19T19:08:12.724945+0
```

```
$hashtable.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                              System.Object
```

also the suggestion below to use

$hashtable.Value | Where-Object { $_.PR.EndsWith('DS-8069') }

results in both the Date CD and PR being returned.

```
CD                               PR
--                               --
2023-06-15T00:52:35.098398+00:00 refs/heads/DS-8069
2023-06-13T20:22:54.930335+00:00 refs/heads/DS-8069
2023-06-01T13:35:00.489204+00:00 refs/heads/DS-8069
2023-05-25T18:46:50.730473+00:00 refs/heads/DS-8069
2023-05-25T15:30:22.365479+00:00 refs/heads/DS-8069
```

i am hope to just get the dates (CD)

Comment: thats not a hashtable but an array of objects. `$hashtable.Value | Where-Object { $_.PR.EndsWith('DS-8069') }` seems appropriate for this specific question

Comment: What are the keys in `$hashtable`? (show us the output from just `$hashtable`)

Comment: Sorry could not get a good format for response here so adding to text above.

Comment: @LanceLyons You did the exact right thing, comments are not for extensive code or information that should be part of the question in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks.  That does the trick.   I am curious how do you know if its a list, hashtable or array of objects.   Is there an easy way to query the object like  $hashtable.GetType() or something of that nature?

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments, the data you're working with appears to be a list or an array of objects with 2 properties CD and PR each.

> How can I pull the date CD where the PR value contains some text?

Use `Where-Object` to filter the data based on one or more property values:

```
$matchingObjects = $hashtable['value'] |Where-Object PR -like '*DS-8069'
```

... and then use either `ForEach-Object` or `Select-Object` to grab just the property value or the subset of properties you're interested in outputting:

```
$CDValues = $matchingObjects |ForEach-Object CD
# or 
$CDValues = $matchingObjects |Select-Object -ExpandProperty CD
```

If you want the output to be a list of objects each with a `CD` property (but not the `PR` property), use `Select-Object` instead:

```
$CDValueObjects = $matchingObjects |Select -Property CD
# you can also construct the same output by _excluding_ PR
$CDValueObjects = $matchingObjects |Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PR
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the earlier example, the following will return only the values.

> $hashtable.getenumerator() | where {$_.PR.EndsWith('DS-8069')} | Select -ExpandProperty CD